# How to perform animation in Android AndEngine?

Tags: android, animation, andengine

When I have to move some sprite on my scene (for example, on 100px down), I'm using this code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    delay+=frameDelay;
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sprite.setPosition(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY()+10);
            }
        },delay);
}
```

It works, but I wonder if there is much correct and/or more fast possibilities to do this.

Comment: Are you using AndEngine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

or look at the various Modifiers available - to move up/down, use a MoveYModifier - something like

```
yourSprite.registerEntityModifier(new MoveYModifier(time, startY, endY, new IEntityModifierListener() {
                @Override
                public void onModifierStarted(final IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, final IEntity pItem) {
                    yourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Do anything here that you want to happen when the Modifier starts - like start a sound playing, etc
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onModifierFinished(final IModifier<IEntity> pEntityModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {
                    yourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Do anything here that you want to happen after the Modifier is through - like stop playing a sound, etc
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, EaseBounceOut.getInstance()));
```

The EaseBounceOut.getInstance() is just an example  - it causes the Sprite to bounce at the end - there are lots of other EaseFunctions available.